# How to prevent Bootstrap's glyphicon rendering to emoji (Opera, FF)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, opera, mozilla, emoji, glyphicons

I would like to know how to prevent showing emojis from bootstrap's glyphicons?

This

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tent"></span>
```

Renders to this (opera, moz)

[image]

I Stumbled across this:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome

Unicode here :

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26fa/index.htm

Solution: Update your Bootstrap to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Better alternative to avoid such problems is to use font-awesome instead of twitter bootstrap glyphicons and as a bonus you could get more icon set than glyphicons provide.  But if you still want to use bootstrap glyphicons it is better to copy the unicode for that glyphicons (since glyphicons use unicode internally) and append the code as given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip) answer.

Answer (score 0):

use i tag insted of span like `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tent"></i>` may be it will help